# extraer datos de un archivo txt delimitado por "|" y pasar a un archivo csv en python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, txt

estoy tratando de extraer cierta información de un archivo .TXT
por lo que pienso primero tengo que pasar esa información a una matriz para luego recorrerla y extraer el dato de la posición donde se encuentra.
para después agregar esa información a un archivo .CSV

desde ya muchas gracias por su tiempo y ayuda.

se despide atentamente.

Valentin Morales

el codigo que estoy utilizando es el siguiente: tener en cuenta que es en lenguaje python.

```
import pandas as pd

datos=pd.read_csv('factura.txt', header = None, sep ='|')
print(datos)
```

el error que me arroja al compilar es el siguiente:

> runfile('C:/Users/vmorales/Documents/programas python/pasar txt a
>   csv/test2.py', wdir='C:/Users/vmorales/Documents/programas
>   python/pasar txt a csv') Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\vmorales\Documents\programas python\pasar txt a
>   csv\test2.py", line 3, in 
>       datos=pd.read_csv('factura.txt', header = None, sep ='|')
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\vmorales\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py",
>   line 676, in parser_f
>       return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\vmorales\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py",
>   line 454, in _read
>       data = parser.read(nrows)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\vmorales\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py",
>   line 1133, in read
>       ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\vmorales\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py",
>   line 2037, in read
>       data = self._reader.read(nrows)
>
> File "pandas_libs\parsers.pyx", line 859, in
>   pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read
>
> File "pandas_libs\parsers.pyx", line 874, in
>   pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory
>
> File "pandas_libs\parsers.pyx", line 928, in
>   pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
>
> File "pandas_libs\parsers.pyx", line 915, in
>   pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
>
> File "pandas_libs\parsers.pyx", line 2070, in
>   pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
>
> ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 9 fields in line
>   2, saw 11

enlace del archivo.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/12pymN5dky6qFz5ns0yQf8t9Mh16couH7/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hola Valentin, te damos la bienvenida a [es.so]. El error indica que la primera fila tiene 9 columnas y la segunda 11, o usas el separador incorrecto o simplemente no tienes un csv váldio. Por favor agrega las primeras lineas del archivo para poder reproducir el problema. Si hay información sensible debes substituirla pero de tal forma que el problema se siga pudiendo reproducir. Para añadir más información simplemente usa el botón [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/333756/edit) que hay debajo de la pregunta.  Un saludo.

Comment: gracias por la pronta respuesta.

Comment: Como comentaba arriba, no tienes un csv válido, tienes filas con 6, 9, 11, 18, etc columnas, otras filas solo contienen una virgulilla (una columna), Los tipos de datos tampoco coinciden en una misma columna, etc. Va a ser complicado para cualquier parser csv tragar con él. ¿Tiene el archivo alguna estructura definida de antemano, es decir bloques de x lineas que se repitan por ejemplo?

Comment: el tema es que tengo muchos archivos que se generan de la misma forma (facturas), desde un programa que esta hecho en cobol ("ufff muy antiguo", jaaa), el tema es que no tengo los fuentes de ese cobol y al momento de crear el documento es asi.

Comment: para contextualizar, estos archivos son creados por un progrma que esta hecho en cobol, (muy antiguo, jajaja), no tengo los fuentes para realizar algun cambio.
por lo tanto vi que python es super amigable para programar. (si existe alguna otra forma, favor indicarla).
por lo tanto lo que quiero hacer es tomar estos archivos extraer solo algunos campos que están entre PIPE "|" y pasarlos a un archivo CSV, para poder subirlos en forma masiva. al portal que necesito esta información.
lo otro que me dijeron que podía hacerlo es por JSON (pero de eso se nada).

Comment: ¿Que campos quieres extraer exactamente?¿Cada archivo es una sola factura y todas tiene la misma estructura? No es posible usar csv pero obtener los datos que deseas si que es posible sin duda, siempre que exista una estructura perfectamente definida y regular en todos los casos.

Comment: estos son los campos que necesito.
(dte,fecha,vencimiento,forma pago,glosa,rut receptor,razon social,giro,telefono,email,direccion,comuna,codigo,exento,item,descripcion,cantidad,unidad,precio)

 había pensado primero separar por linea y delimitar por los pipe "|".
eso agregarlo a un arreglo.
como es la misma estructura para todos los archivos (aun que si lleva mas item la factura, se deberán agregar).
entonces leer con alguna condición el arreglo y después pasarlo de alguna forma y armar el archivo csv.

Comment: alguna novedad?